# Adjust space in front of opening bracket

Tags: spacing, brackets, white-space

How can I globally reduce the space in front of the opening bracket, i.e. between `M` and `[`? I have to set the brackets with `\left[` and `\right]`. I know that I individually can insert a negative space by `\!` but this is not what I want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$A_M\left[3\right], M\left[3\right]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you could think of removing \left and \right.

Comment: I need \left and \right as my formulas are more complicated than the minimal example.

Comment: If you need to use LaTeX the [mleftright](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright?lang=en) package could be helpful for this situation.

Comment: but you should only use left when you need it otherwise, as you see, it  adds unwanted space

Comment: @mickep The Package mleftright is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @mickep a solution would be to use the package [mleftright](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright?lang=en). See the shorter space in the second row.

[image].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
$\\A_M\left[3\right], M\left[3\right]\\
A_M\mleft[3\mright], M\mleft[3\mright]$
\end{document}
```